# What are the better words to describe difficulty levels?

Tags: word-choice

I'm using five words to describe the difficulty levels of some training material:

> 'Easy', 'Normal', 'Hard', 'Challenging', 'Level 5'

'Level 5' is the most difficult level. I haven't found a proper word for that.
Anyway, I first want to know some better words to name the five levels. The words are not necessarily related to any professional field because it contains training material from different professional fields.

If no better words are available, please help me with a word 'Level 5'.

Comment: Apparently, you are new here: welcome to EL&U. Jenny, you would always better wait for a couple of days before accepting an answer, so as to let enough people see your question and answer it. You can then select the best suited answer. In any case, not within the first hour!

Comment: Expert?  Professional?  Mission Impossible?

Comment: For professional training materials, "difficulty level" doesn't seem appropriate at all. Something more like "Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced" referring to the amount of training previously accomplished is probably more constructive.

Comment: Quake3 used "impossible" or "nightmare" level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One adjective used fairly often in the context of graded puzzles is *Fiendish*.

We seem to be getting into lists or extended discussions...

Comment: Fiendish, that sounds like really very difficult! Thanks!

Comment: This is a nice one.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you the following:

1. Beginner
2. Easy
3. Normal
4. Hard
5. Very hard

Comment: Hey, hit-and-runner! Why the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps because you wrote: "[I would recommend you](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/recommend)"? Unfortunately, there are users who are both pedants *and* unhelpful.

Comment: I think beginner is not a difficulty level, it is more like a proficiency level.

Answer (score 2):

You may use *very easy*, *easy*, *average*, *difficult* and *very difficult*.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty level after
'*Easy*', '*Normal*', '*Hard*', '*Challenging*'
could be

Level 5: ***Command*** level
when the player will gain complete command over the game.

Comment: what game are you talking about?